# How to fix: for loops not reading for a vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

School assignment for coding a cows and bulls game. Final scoring loops not working and I am not sure what the reason is.

I have tried renaming the vectors, changing iterators, changing where in the code the vectors are declared/initialized (still not sure exactly the difference)

```
//Get Number to Guess
if (numlen == 0) {
    cout << "Enter the number to guess: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Enter the number of digits in code: ";
    cin >> numlen;
    numstr = to_string(num);
    if (numstr.length() < numlen) {
        int diff = numlen - numstr.length();
        addz = (diff, "0");
        for (int z = 1; z <= diff; ++z) {
            numstr = addz + numstr;
        }
        num = stoi(numstr);
    }
    vector<int> numvct(numlen, 0);
    max1 = 1;
    for (l = 1; l < numlen; ++l) {
        max1 = max1 * 10;
    }
    for (j = max1, k = 0; j >= 1, k < numlen; j = j / 10, ++k) {
        int addval1 = num / j;
        num = num - (addval1 * j);
        numvct.at(k) = addval1;
    }
    cout << "Number to guess: ";
    for (r = 0; r < numlen; ++r) {
        if (r == (numlen - 1)) {
            cout << numvct.at(r) << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << numvct.at(r) << "-";
        }
    }
}

else {
    //Fill vector to pick from
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
        pickvct.push_back(i);
    }

    //Pull to random number
    vector<int> numvct(numlen);
    for (k = 0; k < numlen; ++k) {
        tempnum1 = rand() % (pickvct.size() - 1);
        numvct.at(k) = pickvct.at(tempnum1);
        pickvct.erase(pickvct.begin() + tempnum1);
    }
    cout << "Number to guess: ";
    for (r = 0; r < numlen; ++r) {
        if (r == (numlen - 1)) {
            cout << numvct.at(r) << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << r << "-";
        }
    }
}

//Get guess
do {
    do {
        cout << "Enter guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        guessstr = to_string(guess);
        guesslen = guessstr.length();
        if (guesslen < numlen) {
            int diff = numlen - guesslen;
            addz = (diff, "0");
            for (int z = 1; z <= diff; ++z) {
                guessstr = addz + guessstr;
            }
            guess = stoi(guessstr);
            guesssame = true;
        }
        if (guesslen == numlen) {
            guesssame = false;
        }
        while (guesslen > numlen) {
            cout << "You can only enter " << numlen << " digits." << endl;
            cout << "Enter guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guessstr = to_string(guess);
            guesslen = guessstr.length();
        }
        for (s = 0; s < guesslen; ++s) {
            for (t = s + 1; t < guesslen; ++t) {
                if (guessstr.at(s) == guessstr.at(t)) {
                    guesssame = true;
                }
                else {
                    guesssame = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (guesssame == true) {
            cout << "Each number must be different." << endl;
            guesssame = true;
        }
    } while (guesssame == true);
    vector<int> guessvct(guesslen, 0);
    max2 = 1;
    for (m = 1; m < guesslen; ++m) {
        max2 = max2 * 10;
    }
    for (n = max2, o = 0; n >= 1, o < guesslen; n = n / 10, ++o) {
        addval2 = guess / n;
        guess = guess - (addval2 * n);
        guessvct.at(o) = addval2;
    }

    //Check the guess
    for (p = 0; p < guesslen; ++p) {
        guessdigit = guessvct.at(p);
        cout << "Guess digit at " << p << ": " << guessdigit << endl;
        for (q = 0; q < guesslen; ++q) {
            numdigit = numvct.at(q);
            cout << "Num digit at " << q << ": " << numdigit << endl;
            if (numdigit == guessdigit && q == p) {
                bulls = bulls + 1;
                if (bulls == numlen) {
                    win = true;
                    break;
                }
                cout << bulls << " bulls" << endl;
            }
            else {
                if (numdigit == guessdigit && q != p) {
                    cows = cows + 1;
                    cout << cows << " cows" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} while (win == false);
```

To make sure the loop was working right I added the cout statements but it is printing the first one only:
Enter guess: ####
Guess digit at 0: #
*Program finished*

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is the expected output?

Comment: I was expecting it to iterate through both vectors and check the digits something like:
Enter Guess: 1234 (endl)
Guess digit at 0: 1 (endl)
Num digit at 0: 5 (endl)
Num digit at 1: 3 (endl)
so on and so forth

Comment: What is `addz`?  `addz = (diff, "0")` is probably not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Try debugging using [gdb](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-use-gdb)

Comment: The addz is a specific thing they wanted. IE they can enter the 0 and put their own code in and it will add zeros to the front to fill it to the correct digits, ie 59 becomes 059.

Comment: I don't know what half the stuff on the gbd website means. I wouldn't know what to do with that. I am very new at this

Comment: I would suggest breaking your problem down into smaller pieces and verifying each of those works and you understand why. As an example, `addz = (diff, "0");` is the equivalent of `addz = "0"` but you seem to think it does something else. By reducing the program to smaller chunks it will be easier to see where the problem is and perhaps you edit this down to a small [mcve] with a specific question. You can always edit your question to add more detail, like exactly what output you are expecting for a given input.

Comment: But how is `addz` declared? Is at an `int`, a `string`, a `char *`, a function, or something else?

Comment: Everything else works fine. Just the final loops are the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get Number to Guess
if (numlen == 0) {
  ...
}

else {
  //Fill vector to pick from
  ...
}
```

Within this if else block, you have the following two lines:

```
vector<int> numvct(numlen, 0);
```

and

```
vector<int> numvct(numlen);
```

These lines declare and initialize vectors which pass out of scope when the program leaves their respective if / else blocks. You use this vector numvct again later, though, so I assume you also declared and initialized it before any of the shown code, and it probably starts off empty. Because those two numvct vectors within the if / else block pass out of scope, all the work you do to them goes away aswell. That means that when you try to use numvct again later, you're working with the (presumably) empty one that you declared at the very beginning of the program.

Instead of redeclaring numvct, try just resizing it:

```
//vector<int> numvct(numlen);
      numvct.resize(numlen);
```

and

```
//vector<int> numvct(numlen, 0);
      numvct.resize(numlen, 0);
```

Also you might want to try cutting down on the number of variables you're using here, and try to declare them only within the code blocks where they are really needed. It will make it easier to keep track of what's going on.

Edit: I just want to add that I suggest resizing the vectors, as opposed to any other operation you could perform on a vector, because I don't really know what your exact intended use for them was. I ran your code with these changes, as well as with the addition of ~25 other variable declarations that you did not include in your post, and it did things that seemed reasonable i.e. allowed me to choose a number, guess its digits, print number of cows and bulls etc.

Comment: That made them iterate through, thanks. Now to make sure everything else works